# authentification is not comparing values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

ok, i have a mongodb server inside it i have a database called userdbs for storing the users that signup using my http://localhost:8085/add-user ,after registration it redirect the user to the login page which have the following address http://localhost:8085/login ,the registration process works fine, but when it comes to authentification i got an error, for exemple i have in the dabase a user with an email : "exemple@domain.com" password:"password" when i try to do the the authentification i get the following error:

> {"message":"E11000 duplicate key error collection:
> myFirstDatabase.userdbs index: email_1 dup key: { email:
> "exemple@domain.com" }"}

here is the code in the controller.js:

```
var Userdb = require('../model/model');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// create and save new user
exports.create = async(req,res)=>{
    // validate request
    if(!req.body){
        res.status(400).send({ message : "Content can not be emtpy!"});
        return;
    }
    
    
    
    // new user
    const user = new Userdb({
        name : req.body.name,
        username : req.body.username,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    })
    

    


    // save user in the database
    user
        .save(user)
        .then(data => {
            //res.send(data)
            res.redirect('/login');
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(500).send({
                message : err.message || "Some error occurred while creating a create operation"
            });
        });


 
}


//searching for user and doing comparaison
exports.login = async(req, res) => {

    const user = Userdb.find(user => user.email = req.body.email);
        if(user == null)
        {
            return res.status(400).send('cannot find user');
        }
    
        try 
        {
            if(req.body.password == user.password)
                res.send("Success")
            else
                res.send("username/password incorrect")
        }
        catch
        {
            res.status(500).send();
        }
    
}
```

here is the api routes in the router.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router()

const services = require('../services/render');
const controller = require('../controller/controller');

/**
 *  @description Root Route
 *  @method GET /
 */
route.get('/', services.homeRoutes);

/**
 *  @description add users
 *  @method GET /add-user
 */
route.get('/add-user', services.add_user)

/**
 *  @description login users
 *  @method POST /login
 */
route.get('/login', services.login)


/**
 *  @description for update user
 *  @method GET /update-user
 */
route.get('/update-user', services.update_user)


// API
route.post('/api/users', controller.create);
route.get('/api/users', controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id', controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id', controller.delete);


module.exports = route
```

and here its the render.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');


exports.homeRoutes = (req, res) => {
    // Make a get request to /api/users
    axios.get('http://localhost:8085/api/users')
        .then(function(response){
            res.render('index', { users : response.data });
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.send(err);
        })

    
}

exports.add_user = (req, res) =>{
    res.render('add_user');
}

exports.login = (req, res) =>
{
    res.render('login');
}

exports.update_user = (req, res) =>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:_085/api/users', { params : { id : req.query.id }})
        .then(function(userdata){
            res.render("update_user", { user : userdata.data})
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.send(err);
        })
}
```

the model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required: false
    },
    
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: true
    },
    
    email : {
        type: String,
        requird: true,
        unique: true
    },
    
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true
}


})

const Userdb = mongoose.model('userdb', schema);

module.exports = Userdb;
```

mongoose connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    try{
        // mongodb connection string
        const con = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB connected : ${con.connection.host}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

here is the server.js if its needed:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');

const app = express();

dotenv.config( { path : 'config.env'} )
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8085

// log requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// mongodb connection
connectDB();

// parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended : true}))

// set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
//app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "views/ejs"))

// load assets
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets")))


// load routers
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(PORT, ()=> { console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)});
```

also forget to mention both views login.ejs and add-user.ejs have the same for action

```
<form action="/api/users" method="POST">
```

I appreciate your consideration/guidance/help/time

Comment: How do your data look like? If email `exemple@domain.com` is already present in the database, then the behaviour is correct. You have also a typo in the model: `requird` instead of `required`.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/UmYLmZAScdOn here its @<user14967413> @user14967413

Comment: `exemple@domain.com` is already present in your collection, so the error *duplicate key error collection* is correct, because you declared username as unique in the model.

Comment: my problem is that im trying authentification so i want to server to redirect me to home page or send success msg instead of that msg let me show you my views

Comment: login : https://prnt.sc/KPwJJ14oYPQ8
add-user: https://prnt.sc/gvyRn9sb3xT_

Comment: yet i removed the unique attribute, and i got into new problem that in authentification page the user and password are being saved in database which is not logical at lol

Comment: i dont know if its allowed or not for security purpose in stackoverflow but i can link you the github full project if you want

Comment: Check the URL for login on client side. Maybe the client calls add-user instead of login. You don't even have `controller.login` in the router. You should probably add `route.post('/login', controller.login)`.

Comment: ty so much it worked, may you added to answer so i can upvote it

Comment: i tried to : but its says i need to have at least 15 reo to be able to upvote yours :( im sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL for login on client side. Maybe the client calls add-user instead of login.

Moreover, the route for login is missing, you should add it to router.js file:

```
route.post('/login', controller.login)
```